# TikZ: Is \tikztonodes incompatible with arc?

Tags: tikz-pgf, mactex

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, decorations.text, decorations.pathmorphing, decorations.markings, positioning, shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{
  fermion/.style = {draw = black, postaction = {decorate},decoration = {markings,mark = at position .55 with {\arrow{>}}}},
  vertex/.style = {draw,shape = circle,fill = black,minimum size = 2pt,inner sep = 0pt},
  semiloop/.style = {to path={
    let 
        \p1 = ($(\tikztotarget)-(\tikztostart)$),
        \n1 = {atan2(\y1,\x1)},
        \n2 = {0.5*veclen(\x1,\y1)}
    in 
        arc[start angle=(\n1+180), delta angle=(-180), radius=(\n2)] (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes
  }},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 1cm and 1cm]
\coordinate[vertex] (v1);
\coordinate[vertex, right = of v1] (v2);
\coordinate[vertex, right = of v2] (v3);
\coordinate[vertex, right = of v3] (v4);
\draw[fermion] (v2) to[semiloop] node[above=0.1cm] {$q$} (v3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

It fails with

```
Errors:

./tex-stackexchange-question.tex:27: Missing number, treated as zero. [... to[semiloop] node[above=0.1cm] {$q$} (v3)]
./tex-stackexchange-question.tex:27: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). [... to[semiloop] node[above=0.1cm] {$q$} (v3)]
./tex-stackexchange-question.tex:27: Missing number, treated as zero. [... to[semiloop] node[above=0.1cm] {$q$} (v3)]
./tex-stackexchange-question.tex:27: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). [... to[semiloop] node[above=0.1cm] {$q$} (v3)]
```

If I then replace arc[...] with --, the code typesets fine. If I keep arc[...] but remove \tikztonodes, it typesets fine too. Is this a bug? Is there a workaround?

I used MacTeX 2014.

Thanks in advance for any help.

**Update**

First, I forgot to mention I used pdflatex and that my distro has tikz/pgf version 3, according to the documentation.

Then, thanks to @percusse and @cfr, the syntax error is gone but now the placement is not working. It has nothing to do with \tikztonodes or even with styles actually, as demonstrated by the following snippet where the half loop is drawn "by hand". I added labels to the vertices and contrasted two approaches which should be equivalent imho.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, decorations.text, decorations.pathmorphing, decorations.markings, positioning, shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{
  fermion/.style = {draw = black, postaction = {decorate},decoration = {markings,mark = at position .55 with {\arrow{>}}}},
  vertex/.style = {draw,shape = circle,fill = black,minimum size = 2pt,inner sep = 0pt},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 1cm and 1cm]
\coordinate[vertex, label = below:$v_1$] (v1);
\coordinate[vertex, right = of v1, label = below:$v_2$] (v2);
\coordinate[vertex, right = of v2, label = below:$v_3$] (v3);
\coordinate[vertex, right = of v3, label = below:$v_4$] (v4);
\draw[fermion]
let
    \p1 = ($(v3)-(v2)$),
    \n1 = {atan2(\y1,\x1)},
    \n2 = {0.5*veclen(\x1,\y1)}
in 
    (v2) arc[start angle={\n1+180}, delta angle=-180, radius=\n2] node[midway, above=0.1cm] {$q$} (v3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 1cm and 1cm]
\coordinate[vertex, label = below:$v_1$] (v1);
\coordinate[vertex, right = of v1, label = below:$v_2$] (v2);
\coordinate[vertex, right = of v2, label = below:$v_3$] (v3);
\coordinate[vertex, right = of v3, label = below:$v_4$] (v4);
\draw[fermion] (v2) arc[start angle=180, delta angle=-180, radius=0.55cm] node[midway, above=0.1cm] {$q$} (v3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The version with `let ... in ...` and the version without do not put the label **q** at the same place as shown on the following rendering.

[image: rendering]

This is a bug, surely?

**Update (bis)**

For future reference, here is the list of all loaded packages with their version:

pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2014.9.23)

- everyshi 2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
- graphics 2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
- graphicx 2014/04/25 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
- keyval 2014/05/08 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
- pgf 2013/12/18 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.14)
- pgfcomp-version-0-65 2007/07/03 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.7)
- pgfcomp-version-1-18 2007/07/23 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.1)
- pgfcore 2010/04/11 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.7)
- pgffor 2013/12/13 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.25)
- pgfrcs 2013/12/20 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.28)
- pgfsys 2013/11/30 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.47)
- tikz 2013/12/13 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.142)
- trig 1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
- xcolor 2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

I have filled a bug report. Thanks a lot to all of you who have given answers.

My conclusion: the Tikz is too brittle to base my work on it. I will try to develop a solution based on the PGF basic layer instead.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! Try `node[above=0.1cm of nodename]`?

Comment: Thanks @cfr but `node[above=0.1cm of v2]` for example gives me the same errors.

Comment: Only the 2nd fix works for me. Replacing the arc gets the same compilation error.

Comment: It works if you go straight to `(v3)`. I think you cannot add another to-node there when you already have to-nodes since it isn't specified yet? Maybe?

Comment: That is, e.g. `\draw[fermion] (v2) to[semiloop] (v3)  node[above=6mm of {$(v2)!1/2!(v3)$}] {$q$};` works with the existing definition of `semiloop`.

Comment: Use `arc[start angle={\n1+180}, delta angle=-180, radius=\n2]` it will fix the errors but the nodes are placed wrongly. So I'll try to check it later.

Comment: I came to compile your second code with PDFLaTeX and XeLaTeX (PGF 3.0) and everything is ok for me : no displacement of $q$ label. Note : you have useless `\usetikzlibrary{}` in the code.

Comment: Thanks for the input @Kpym. Could you tell me exactly which version of pdflatex you have? On which platform?

Comment: I'm on Windows using MikTeX as shown here `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2014.3.26)  10 DEC 2014 09:28` with `Package: pgf 2013/12/18 v3.0.0-cvs (rcs-revision 1.14)`

Comment: I came to check on my mac : and there is the problem you mention. If you replace `\n1 = {atan2(\y1,\x1)}` by `\n1 = {atan2(\y1,\x1)+180}` and you put just `start angle={\n1}` it works correctly. I think the problem is that putting `start angle={\n1+180}` do not expand correctly. You have to evaluate it before to passe the value to `start angle`.

Comment: @Kpym If I replace all macros with numbers I can still replicate the error. This something to do with a transformation somewhere. Notice that the curve is drawn correctly each time regardless of the input so if that was the case the curve should have been affected by it also.

Comment: @percusse well it depends : if you replace \n1 by 0 there is compilation error, but if you replace it by 0pt or by 0.0pt (this is the actual value of \n1) the lable is displaced. Question 1: Why atan2 gives something with pt ? (angles are not mesured in pts). Question 2 : Why `start angle={0+180}` ask for units but `start angle={180}` is ok ?

Comment: @Kpym pgfmath does computations via tex dimens so internally it converts everything. That's normal. In the second part of it, you do math via `0+180` so dimens are involved `\pgf@x` stuff. The other one only parses the number so it passes.

Comment: @percusse even if pgfmath use internaly dimens when you calculate `atan2{1}{2}` there is no units, so in my opinion `atan2` should strip out the units (or put angle units ;)). By the way pgfmath knows how to calculate `0+180` very well ... no ?

Comment: @Kpym there is a difference between what `let` uses within `calc` library and what you get out of `pgfmathresult`

Comment: @percusse you are right : `\n1` is 0.0pt but `\pgfmathparse{atan2(\y1,\x1)}\pgfmathresult` is 0.0 ! In the documentation of let for \n assignment we can reed 'When an assignment has this form, the <formula> is evaluated using the \pgfmathparse operation.', so where is the bug? Anyway this seems not to be the problem because on my PC the problem is not present (I can put `start angle={0+180}` or `{0pt+180}` or `{0.0pt+180}` without any error) and on my Mac nothing works properly and both have the same evaluation of `atan2`.

Comment: If you use `start angle={180+\n1}` instead of `start angle={\n1+180}`, you got an error. With the [CVS version of TikZ/pgf](http://pgf.sourceforge.net/), you got two identical pictures. So, this bug was fixed.

Comment: I think this may be off-topic because it is about a bug that has been fixed in a subsequent release of `pgf`.